# iOS: Implement UITableView using MVC

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I couldn't find an example with good explanation how to include UITableView in my project using MVC pattern.
Let's say that at the beginning I have only two files 'MainViewController' (:UIViewController), and 'MainModel' (:NSObject) containing my Array with data for cells.

Where I should have a  reference to UITableView object, which file should be delegate for table, ... ?

Comment: try UITableViewController first

Comment: unfortunately I want to  understand how to divide my code into Model View and Controller, without subclassing UITableViewController :)

Comment: UITableView - view, knows only about how to draw itself, UIViewController (or UITableViewController as a subclass of) - controller, knows where ans what data needs to be displayed (or refreshed) on managed by it's own view and about user actions, Model - some class (classes mechanism), knows nothing about drawing and fetching, but let's know about it's own state (objects states) changes to interested subscribers. So, why don't you want to subclass UITableViewController?

Answer (score 1):

Your `MainViewController` will have a `view` property that you should point to your `UITableView` instance. You can have any object be your delegate, but usually your delegate is the view controller that controls it, which would be your `MainViewController`.

That said, there's a subclass of `UIViewController` called `UITableViewController` that you should probably be using as the superclass of `MainViewController`. It has some automatic functionality for controlling UITableViews. In fact, instantiating a `UITableViewController` (or any its subclasses) will automatically create a UITableView and point to it in its `view` & `tableView` properties.

Answer (score 0):

So your MainModel is the model. MainViewController is your controller. The tableView is your view. Add it as a property to your MainViewController and set your MainViewController to be the dataSource and delegate for the tableView. Then when you are populating the tableView, use the data in your MainModel. For instance:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [[MainModel sharedInstance] myArray].count;
}
```

Or create an NSArray property on MainViewController and populate it from MainModel in viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear.